# How to abstract a random data getter for Django?

Tags: django, django-models, random

i have a piece of code to get random data from database:

```
def get_random_item(model,queryset,id_column_name): 
    max_id = getattr(model.objects.order_by('-%s'%id_column_name)[0],id_column_name)
    min_id = math.ceil((max_id-100000)*random.random()) + 100000
    return queryset.filter(**content_id**__gte=min_id)[0]
```

as u can see,i want to abstract a function for any model,but i don't know how to replace the "content_id",cauz it's not a string or simply an attribute but with __gte.

tks for your answers~

Comment: You do realize that your code can't handle holes in the PK properly, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["The pk lookup shortcut"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

> For convenience, Django provides a `pk` lookup shortcut, which stands for "primary key".

Answer (score 0):

You can try queryset.filter(**{"%s__gte" % (column_name,): min_id)

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)